# html form - how to call different php pages based on the button selected

Tags: php, html, forms, action

Problem: How to make an HTML Form call different php pages from the action based on what button is pushed?

The code below is the solution I have now, but I figure there must be a better way to do this then creating multiple forms on the page?

```
<html>  
<body>
    <form name="entry_form" action="entry_update_script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="entry_id" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="entry_item_id" value="">
        Truck/Railcar/Barge#:<input type="text" name="pro_number" value=""><br>
        BOL #:<input type="text" name="bol" value=""><br>
        <input type="submit" name="entry_submit" value="Add New Entry!">
    </form>
    <form name="entry_form_add" action="entry_view.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="entry_id" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add New Item!">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<html>  
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function submitAction(act) {
         document.sample.action = act;
         document.sample.submit();

    }
    </script>
    <form name ="sample" action="default.php">
         <input type="button" value = "blah1" onClick="submitAction('phpPage1.php')">
         <input type="button" value = "blah2" onClick="submitAction('phpPage2.php')">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry i see you want to use buttons ill work up an edit real quick

Comment: haha on poop.  So I'm new to all this but this would be changing the DOM based on javascript?  I'm guessing I could just change type to Submit?

Comment: correct, in javascript you are modifying the action attribute on your named form. You can use buttons if you want. Calling submit() submits the form programmatically the same way as clicking an <input type="submit"> button

Answer (score -2):

you might choose the page to go from a dispatcher, it's an extensible and robust solution:

**your form**

```
<form action="dispatcher.php" method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="myOption" value="register" />
    <input type="radio" name="myOption" value="login" />
</form>
```

**dispatcher.php**

```
$actions = array ('register', 'login');

// validate possible actions
if (in_array($_POST['myOption']), $actions)) {
    include ($_POST['myOption'] . '.php');
}
```